# How to store console output into text file and each run it should create a new text file

Tags: java, jdbc

Can anyone suggest/help how to store this code output in text file, it should create a new text file in each run and stored in specified path.
Appreciate your help and support:

```
   import java.io.*;  
    import java.sql.*;  

    public class RetrieveFile {  
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("123.23.32.12:8080/orcl", "test", "****");

                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from MSG where MID='1234'");
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                try {
                    printResultColumns(rs);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }

                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void printResultColumns(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException {
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            // you get a single result row in here, not the entire ResultSet
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                switch (rsmd.getColumnType(i)) {
                case Types.VARCHAR:
                case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
                case Types.CHAR:
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getString(i));
                    break;
                case Types.DOUBLE:
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getDouble(i));
                    break;
                case Types.INTEGER:
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(i));
                    break;
                case Types.DATE:
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getDate(i).toString());
                    break;
                case Types.TIMESTAMP:
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getTimestamp(i).toString());
                    break;
                case Types.BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getBoolean(i));
                    break;
                case Types.DECIMAL:
                case Types.NUMERIC:
                    System.out.println(resultSet.getBigDecimal(i));
                    break;
                default:
                    //System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnClassName(i)
                    //System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnType(i));
                    String data = String.valueOf(i); 


                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Ppp\\pp.txt");

                fos.write(data.getBytes());
                fos.close();


                }
            }
        }
    }
        }
```

***Console output:-***
    null
    1961108001406E00
    389
    OUR
    NOW
    USD
    0
    0
    FR1
    FRHBFR222954760001
    USD
    0
    null
    0

Thanks in advance.
Updated as per comment

Comment: There are multiple way to create output file for each run.

 - you can create a file you using system date time + some prefix, so
   when you create a file it will create a new file. then you can write
   you result in to it.
 - you can use some prefix + random number as a
   file name then also it will create a new file every time. 
 - you can create file name + count so before creating a new file,  you have to
   check what is your last file count number then do + 1. it will also
   create file during run.
now it is your choice

Comment: And one more thing it would only create file for the **default** case. may be its not reaching the default case so as to write the file using FileOutputStream object.

Answer (score 1):

Just directly write to the file instead of printing it on the console 
Use **FileOutputStream** instead  of **System.out.println**

Incase if you are not sure of the type of data that you are printing is String or Not, then use the method **String.valueOf(arg)** to convert whatever datatype to String

This will also overwrite the file if it already existed.

```
      // 'arg' can be of any datatype it can be int, boolean, float, double etc..
      String data = String.valueOf(arg); 

      String str = "hello";
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("log.txt");

      fos.write(str.getBytes());
      fos.close();
```

**OR**

Type this while running the Java Class file using Command Line. Just for Fun

```
java -cp . RetrieveFils > hello.file
```

Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks Paul, i have updated my code as per ur 1 st solution, but still it's not writing in output file. Can you please have a look, and buide me if i am missing any. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it creating a file ? i mean is it creating a blank file with that name in that location. if not its because you are writing to C: for that you need admin privilege. Run the app as admin or change the drive to some other drive like D: or other drives.

Comment: it's not creating file. I do have access to c drive. Still have changed to desktop location, facing the same issue.

Comment: Try creating a file in the other drive Like D: just try doing it or else its not reaching the **default case** its where you have the file writing parting of your code. Actually writing to file works. Am sure about it as i have personally ran my code before posting it as an answer. so it was creating the file. Is it giving you some exceptions while writing the file.. Is your program crashing ? or make sure its reaching the default case. I am Sorry am unable to understand the issue clearly. if its throwing some exception kindly send it to me and i will take a look and let you know whats wrong.

Comment: Please make sure that folder exists on to which you write the file. If the folder or directory of the given path doesn't exist then the file wont be created. Please try writing to path to relative path (from your project) instead of absolute path. Also please try "C:\\log.txt" or "D:\\log.txt" . and see whether its being created or not.

Comment: thanks Paul please find the console out put-----java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:127)
 at RetrieveFile.printResultColumns(RetrieveFile.java:76)
 at RetrieveFile.main(RetrieveFile.java:14)
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.home=C:\Users\45060